# mv directory to overwrite another

Tags: bash, command, mv

I may be going bonkers here, but I'm trying to move a directory to a new location, overwriting the contents (on Linux, using bash).

Everytime I try it, it responds with "mv: cannot move `./src' to a subdirectory of itself"

eg. I have:

```
/src
/new/dir/src
/$ mv src/ new/dir/
```

If I delete the destination dir, then it works. I know I can move the contents of the source dir to overwrite the destination, but I'd like to use the same command to overwrite the destination if it already exists, or move the source if it doesn't.

Comment: weird, your example works for me...

Comment: a thought: are there any symlinks involved?

Comment: Looks okay to me too...

Comment: yes there is, the 'root' dir is symlinked so it appears elsewhere in th filesystem (not a subdir) but .... I'll investigate that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

try providing the absolute path to each directory.

i.e. `mv /src /new/dir/`

also, you can look into `rsync` to copy files and delete existing files, and all that.

you can also do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -e /new/dir/src/ ]; then
  rm -rf /new/dir/src/
fi
mv /src /new/dir/
```

unless you're concerned with keeping files in `/new/dir/src/`, in which case `rsync` would be a better option.